# VSCode integration with Unity 2017.1: IntelliSense not able to suggest any type of data

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I just heard that Unity will be dropping support on MonoDevelop on its 2018.1 version and went to search for an alternative. VSCode was the best option so I downloaded it and installed all suggested Unity extensions. (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity)

I also changed my External Script Editor to Code. I've created a new Unity project for testing. The code snippets are working great for unity methods such as Start () and Update () but whenever I try to declare a variable like:

```
private Rigidbody rb;
```

The rigid body is not suggested. I decided to test with other data types, the most essentials like int, float, etc. And none of them are suggested either. What could be happening? Why is IntelliSense not working properly? I've already downloaded the C# extension as suggested at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

I'm on a Mac using MacOS Sierra with the most current version of VSCode and Unity 2017.1.

[EDIT] The problem was solved after I reinstalled, MonoDevelop, VisualStudio for Mac, VSCode and all it's extensions and used mad.meesh suggestion of searching the .sln on project opening. I still don't understand why, but it's working.

Comment: did you install `.Net Core` ?

Comment: Yes, after VSCode install I got a warning message saying .NET core could not be found so I download it and installed it.

Comment: next question: did you install the vscode `c# extension` ?

Comment: Yes, I installed with every other extension, at first I thought it was a compatibility error so I uninstalled everything and installed only C# extension but the problem is still happening.

Comment: next question: did you hook up the `.sln` file in vscode? you can do it down in the bottom right or left (little flame looking icon) -- click on it and select the `.sln` related to your unity project

Comment: OK, I followed your instructions and clicked on the sln file. The flame looking icon says "Running" but the editor is still not suggesting not even the essentials like int or float.

Comment: last question: have you restarted unity and stuff? sorry don't know what else it could be without seeing the config myself

Comment: I created a small album to show what I'm talking about: https://imgur.com/a/X4riy

Comment: Yes, I've restarted everything including the computer.

Comment: The problem was solved after I reinstalled, MonoDevelop, VisualStudio for Mac, VSCode and all it's extensions and used your suggestion of searching the .sln on project opening. I still don't understand why, but it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I had the same problem just recently.

There must have been an issue in your **Assembly-CSharp.csproj** or **project-name.sln** files. Most likely to be the *.csproj* file. If you take a look at it, you will see various references to *.dll* files.

You can tell Unity (my version: *v2019.2.20f1*) to create these for you by enabling *Edit* > *Preferences* > **Generate all .csproj files**.

1. Delete both files.
2. Enable .csproj file generation.
3. Double click on a script in Unity.

This fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the tutorial from Microsoft for VS Code with Unity and it seemed to finally do the trick... https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Steps I took:

1. Installed https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download
2. Installed https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/
3. Installed C# extension in VS Code.
4. Unity > Preferences (cmd + , on Mac) > External Tools (left toolbar) > External Script Editor > Visual Studio Code.
5. **Then this is the trick I found to work after doing all of this...**  I open up VS Code prior to starting my Unity Project and manually go into the Unity Project folder and open up everything in VS Code FIRST. Then, with that project already open and working in VS Code with Intellisense, I double click the script in Unity and it will open it up in the already opened VS Code editor and have Intellisense already working! Do my normal workflow for the day and close everything down... then when I start up the next time, just be sure to open the project in VS Code FIRST and then VS Code will recognize it's a C# project and initiate Intellisense and all that jazz.

Hope this helps!